# VB ASP.Net jQuery: change rowspan dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, html-table

I have a jQuery function that removes a row when the CheckBox is clicked.  However, I need to also adjust the rowspan property because there are now fewer rows in the table.  How can I do this in jQuery?  Thanks in advance!

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript"  type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#chkDebtProtect').click(
                function () {
                    alert("hello world");
                    $('.HideMe').hide();
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table>
        <tr  class="tableDataBorder">
            <td rowspan="3" class="leftBorder">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="3" class = "leftMargin">
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" class="TableHeader">
                Online Products
            </td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="tableDataBorder">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkProduct" CssClass="boldIt" style="font-size:.8em; font-style: italic" Text="Are you interented in learning about our product?" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
                <td>
                    Product <br />
                   Info
                </td>
                <td>
                    $&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtProductPrice" BorderColor="Silver" Width="80" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Inset"></asp:TextBox>.00<br />
                </td>
            </tr>      
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: neither i can find #chkDebtProtect nor .Hideme

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```js
$("td.leftBorder").attr("rowspan","2");
```